# Do i need to put inverted commas in services.php?

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I am trying to implement google recaptcha v3 in my laravel application. But my problem is i have to put keys in .env file but when i push into gitlab .env files is  not going to be pushed. So, i decided to put my recaptcha keys in config/service.php file like this.

```
 'recaptcha' => [
        'sitekey' => '6LeL_MoZVVBDAAPe62Sm5Z9A92FNN4oONybbvAXu-',
        'secret' => '6LeL_MoZAAVVVSAI06yiqkoLy5pY1SvtBNzKFMlW9S',
        ],
```

***Keys are fake***
So, my question is should i put '' between those keys or should i keep keys without ('').
Because my google recaptcha is not showing at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Committing sensitive informations like these isn't encouraged. You are expected to have another `.env` on your production server so to protect these sensitive info especially when you are working in a team. But  if you still find the need to do it your way then yes you are supposed to keep it in quotes just as you have it or maybe a double quote, php really doesn't take that into consideration.
As for the the ReCaptcha button  not visible, you might want to check your implementation cuz there is something you not doing right.